# Siamese Neural Network + Classifier (FFN) in Keras

Tags: python, keras, siamese-network

I would try to implement a **Siamese Neural Network** thas has as output not only the similarity metric, but plus also able to classify the labels of each pair of input. The input are semantic audio embeddings.
Actually I have two problems:

1: In a siamese neural network the labels are the "labels of the pair"? Is there the possibility to preserve the label of the single input too? I mean is there the possibility to compute a loss function that combine the loss of the classifier+the similarity metric?

2: Do you think that I should divide the problems? I mean two networks, one is the siamese and then get the output embedding of the siamese and feed the Feed Forward network with the siamese output?(saving the similarity metric and using in the loss function of the second neural network?)

Hope I explain well the problem, and hope that someone has the solution.
Mike

Answer (score 0):

For the first question, you can have a look at https://www.tensorflow.org/guide/keras/train_and_evaluate#custom_losses

There they give an example for how to write a custom loss function.

Comment: Thank you, I actually can make a custom Loss function when I have like only a FFNetwork, I'm struggling because I have two different kind of networks and plus I never trained a Siamese Neural Network.